# Directly scroll to a particular part in android activity using webview

Tags: android

I am new in Android development.

How can I  scroll directly to a particular part in activity? I have used WebView in activity.

Example:
Below is the data in my activity:

January
February
March
April 
May
June
July
August
September
October 
November
December.

I want my activity to directly scroll on October.
How to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WebView you can for example change the scale:

```
yourWebView.setInitialScale(some value which fits your needs);
```

and scroll to a specific position:

```
yourWebView.scrollTo(x,y);
```